# Unwrapping elements from list item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm having trouble unwrapping the anchor tag from the list item.

I have the following markup:

```html
<ul class="yith-wcan-list yith-wcan ">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <small class="count">8</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <small class="count">10</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <small class="count">4</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and I am trying to use jQuery to remove the link from the list item, and surround that list item with that link.

For example my desired code would be:

```html
<ul class="yith-wcan-list yith-wcan ">
  <a href="#">
    <li>Item 1
      <small class="count">8</small>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Item 2
      <small class="count">10</small>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <li>Item 3
      <small class="count">4</small>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

I have the following javascript code but it does not work:

```js
var Links = jQuery('.yith-wcan-list').find('li a');
jQuery(Links[0]).unwrap();
```

Comment: The result you're after would be invalid HTML. An `<a>` can't be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: I understand this may be invalid HTML, however it does work the way I want it to on my browser. I want the entire list item to be a clickable link. If you have any alternative methods to suggest that are valid HTML I would appreciate it.

Comment: _"I want the entire list item to be a clickable link."_ `$(".yith-wcan-list li").on("click", function(){//do stuff})`

Comment: @flippinroo2 It works probably because the browser is trying to correct your HTML, not because it is the right way to do it. You can simply wrap all the content in your `<li>` within `<a>` (i.e. move all the siblings of `<a>` into `<a>`), and that should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in jQuery in 4 steps:

1. Remove the text from inside each anchor;
2. Then remove all the anchors using `detach()`;
3. Then append new anchors to the unordered list, equal to the number of list items;
4. Then move the existing list items into the new anchors

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Remove the text from inside each anchor
    for (var i = 0; i < $('li').length; i++) {
        $('li').eq(i).prepend($('li a').eq(i).text());
    }
    
    // Remove all the anchors
    $('a').detach();
    
    // Append new anchors to the unordered list, equal to the number of list items
    for (var i = 0; i < $('li').length; i++) {
        $('ul').append('<a href="#"></a>');
    }

    // Append the existing list items to the new anchors
    for (var i = 0; i < $('li').length; i++) {
        $('a').eq(i).append($('li').eq(0));
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="yith-wcan-list yith-wcan ">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <small class="count">8</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <small class="count">10</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <small class="count">4</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @j08691 said, `<a>` can't be child of `<ul>`. However, if you desire that, I would probably use this kind of approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.yith-wcan-list.yith-wcan > li").each(function(){
    $(this).children().appendTo($(this).children('a:first'))
    $(this).children('a:first').wrapInner('<li>').unwrap()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="yith-wcan-list yith-wcan ">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <small class="count">8</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <small class="count">10</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <small class="count">4</small>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```